# Unable to understand this code [JavaScript , Dates and Obtaining TimeZones]

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

Please help me to understand this code :-

```
function seconds_with_leading_zeros(dt)   
{   
  return /\((.*)\)/.exec(new Date().toString())[1];  
}  

dt = new Date();   
console.log(seconds_with_leading_zeros(dt));   

dt = new Date(1989, 10, 1);   
console.log(seconds_with_leading_zeros(dt));
```

It is suppose to show user's time zone.

Comment: It returns all the characters inside and including the first () pair which would be the time zone. Though I dont know why it is passed a date object as it is not used.

Comment: Weird. Your function takes a 'dt' parameter but it's not being used

Comment: @Mtihc i didn't created this thing i found this in W3resources and thats one of the reason i'm very confused about this thing plus i do not understand their return statement code

Comment: In most cases, the value in parenthesis is a a human-readable, language-specific, implementation dependent string.  It's not standardized in any way.  What are you trying to accomplish with this output?

Comment: @MattJohnson i'm practicing my JavaScript from W3Resoures , they asked us to display the timeZone of the user since i don't know the answer i checked their given answer but im not able to understand this code.
here is the link to that question if you wanna check it out
http://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-date-exercise-37.php

Answer (score 0):

`new Date().toString()` returns a string like `"Wed Mar 29 2017 15:37:26 GMT+0200 (West-Europa (zomertijd))"` The timezone is inside the round brackets ().

`return /\((.*)\)/.exec("date and time (timezone)")[1];` returns whatever is inside the brackets. In this case it will return the word `"timezone"`

That's as good as i can explain it :)

Comment: can you explain me this part? 
 ****************return /\((.*)\)/.exec************ and why they accessing its index 1 item ???

Comment: It's a `/regular expression/`. This regular expression `(.*)` will match anything. This regular expression `\((.*)\)` will match anything within round brackets. `exec` will evaluate the given string using the regular expression. And it will return an array. The first element of the array (at index 0) is the whole thing. The second element of the array (at index 1) is the first match. You want the first match, because that's what's inside the round brackets.